# Stochastic differential notation in Standard Brownian Market Models

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am trying to become familiar with stochastic integration and stochastic differential notation. I tried to do the following little exercise. In my lecture notes the risky Asset is defined in the following way
$$
\begin{align*}
(1) &\qquad S(t)=S(0)*e^{ \int_{0}^{t} (r(s) \lambda (s)-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \sigma_{n}^2(s) \,)ds + \sum_{n=1}^N\int_{0}^t\sigma_{n}(s)dW_n(s)} \\
(2) &\qquad dS(t)=S(t)[r(t)+\lambda(t)]dt+S(t)\sum_{n=1}^N\sigma_n(t)dW(t)
\end{align*}$$

When I try to show (2) by using (1) and Itô's Lemma I get following Calculation $f(x):=S(0)e^{x}$,

$$R(t):=\int_{0}^{t} (r(s) \lambda (s)-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \sigma_{n}^2(s) \,)ds + \sum_{n=1}^N\int_{0}^t\sigma_{n}(s)dW_n(s)\\$$   $$dS(t)=df(R(t))=S(t)dR(t)+\frac{1}{2}S(t)dR(t)dR(t)\\=S(t)[r(t) \lambda (t)-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N \sigma_{n}^2(t) \,]dt+\sum_{n=1}^NS(t)\sigma_{n}(t)dW_{n}(t)+\frac{1}{2}S(t)\sum_{n=1}^N\sigma_{n}^2(t)dt\\=S(t)r(t)\lambda(t)dt+\sum_{n=1}^NS(t)\sigma_{n}(t)dW_{n}(t)\\$$
Where is my mistake ?  In equation$(2)$ the $S(t)$ is multiplicated with the sum of some Integrals with respect to the Brownian motion. If I do the Calculations, the $S(t)$ is in the sum and is integrated w.r.t the Brownian motion.

Comment: I think in $(1)$ you should have $r(s)+\lambda(s)$ rather than $r(s)\cdot \lambda(s)$

Comment: and with respect to your last statement, in both cases $S$ is integrated wrt to the Brownian motion, is not "outside" by no means notice that $(2)$ is just a formal shorthand for the integral equation $$S(t)=S(0)+\int_0^t [r(s)+\lambda(s)]S(s)ds+\int_0^t \sigma(s)S(s)dW(s)$$ where I assume you just have one $\sigma$ for simplicity